# Can I use Opensearch 2.2?

Tags: magento2.4, opensearch

Opensearch `1.2` is supported with `>= 2.4.3-p2`

Does anyone know if I can use the latest version `(2.2)`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't work for me, only 1.3 is supported. Note that if you try it, Opensearch 2 will update your database to version 2 and it's not backward compatible.

Comment: Hi David, so you are using 1.3 or 1.2? Thank you.

Comment: 1.3. I upgraded to 2 and couldn't go back to 1.3 without reindexing again.